# Why aren't routes loading in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to understand how the `$routeProvider` mechanism works in AngularJS, so I set up a simple app to test different ways of configuring it. But the problem is that simple app is apparently not compiling, so that the user is not able to see and navigate between the routes.  **What specific changes need to be made to [the code at this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/K4DbAb3dUsNSgh7JdQ8E) to get the simple app to compile so that the user is able to navigate between the routes?**

The code is also placed here as follows:

`index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <base href="/" />
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style type="text/css">
    [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak { display: none !important; }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="ng-cloak" ng-cloak="" ng-app="hello">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="navigation">
      <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('home')}">
          <a href="/">home</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('someroute')}">
          <a href="/someroute">some route</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="home.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="someroute.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="navigation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`script.js` is:

```
var hello = angular.module('hello', [ 'ngRoute', 'home', 'someroute', 'navigation' ])
    .config(

            function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

                $routeProvider.when('/', {
                    templateUrl : 'home.html',
                    controller : 'home'
                })
                .when('/someroute', {
                    templateUrl : 'someroute.html',
                    controller : 'someroute'
                }).otherwise('/');

                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

            }
    )
```

`navigation.js` is:

```
angular.module('navigation', ['ngRoute']).controller('navigation', function($scope, $route, $http, $routeParams, $location) {

    $scope.tab = function(route) {
        return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
    };

});
```

`home.js` is:

```
angular.module('home', []).controller('home', function($scope, $http) {

});
```

`home.html` is:

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<div>
    <p>This is the main page!</p>
</div>
```

`someroute.js` is:

```
angular.module('someroute', []).controller('someroute', function($scope, $http) {

});
```

`someroute.html` is:

```
<h1>Some Route</h1>
<div>
    <p>You clicked on some route!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: For starters, you should only have 1 module to match your `ng-app="hello"` instead of defining multiple modules

Comment: @user2341963 I don't understand.  Each route will need its own module so that JavaScript code can be added into each module in a more complex app.  What specifically should I remove to stop duplicate `hello` definitions while still giving each route its own module js file?

Comment: I don't see an issue with breaking your app into modules but I do notice that  none of your js files appear to be loading in plnkr, probably related to the base href tag you're using.

Comment: @paul147 Thank you.  This plnkr code is stripped down from a more complicated version, so that I can understand it.  The `base href` tag in `index.html` and the `html5mode` in `script.js` are there to produce natural routes, so that the browser renders `/` and `/someroute` instead of `/#` and `/#someroute`.  The natural routes work in the more complicated version of the app that I am not showing here, but the problem emerges when I strip the app down to essentials and start trying to re-arrange things.

Comment: plunker doesn't have `angular-route.js` included. Works fine there without html5mode. Have to use dynamically created base tag on plunker also.  [Working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/CMTdibXM8NF0ot0Y825C?p=preview)

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you.  If you want to write it up as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted and +1.

Comment: @charlietfl Your code uses `/#` and `/#someroute`.  How can I get it to use natural routes `/` and `/someroute`?  I could make this a separate question, but I prefer not to clutter the site with excess questions if we can solve an issue by adding this small element to this existing question.  My problem code in the OP used natural routes, and part of your solution was to remove the natural routes.  Can we put the natural routes back in and still get your solution to work?

Comment: need to do that on own page. Can't configure plunker properly to do it

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you.  I would be happy to mark this as accepted and +1 if you are willing to write it as an answer.  Also, I added a small amount of code to your working plnkr to re-create a specific problem which itself is not much more code.  Are you willing to take a look at it?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142172/why-isnt-form-data-defined-in-this-re-usable-service