# Why can't AngularJS view send data to this re-usable service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An AngularJS app needs to re-use multiple custom objects.  I am concerned about creating cluttered, redundant code that is hard to maintain, so I moved re-usable code to a service that can be concisely injected in the controller for each view and then called directly from each html view without cluttering the controllers with redundant code.

The following image illustrates how the service `someclass.js` will be re-used, and thus why it is important to isolate as much of its code as possible in one place:

[image]

I have developed code that partially accomplishes this on my devbox, and I have [posted the code to a plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JInT1u1n79M6HNW7qtNZ). (Thank you to @shakir for getting this plnkr to recreate the problem.) I am also including the code below.

Though clicking a form submit button does cause the form's handler method in the service to be called, the problem is that the object that should contain the form's data is undefined in the someclass.method1() method that should handle the form's data.  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the value of the user-submitted data from the form can be manipulated inside the service's form handling method?**

**The complete requirements for communication between the view and the service (through the controller) are:**

**1.) `someclass.prop1` can have its value printed in the view (this works in the code below), and**

**2.) the `ng-submit` of `confirmForm` can directly call `someclass.method1` as a handler and thus minimize the code in `someroute.js` (this happens in the code below, but the object that should contain the form's data is not defined when `someclass.somemethod1()` is running)**

---

**plnkr code:**

---

Here is [the plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JInT1u1n79M6HNW7qtNZ)  with the call to the service suggested by `@JoaozitoPolo`. The current version is able to call the `someclass.method1()` from the view, but the form data is not passed into the function. So we need to figure out how to pass the form data into the function.

---

**CODE SHOWN HERE ALSO:**

---

The code that (on my devbox) connects the properties and methods of `someview.html` with `someclass.js` (but does not send the data from the form into `someclass.js` during the function call) is included as follows below:

Here is the code for `someclass.js`:

```
angular
.module('someclass', ['ngCookies'])
.service('someclass', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$cookies', function($rootScope, $http, $cookies){

this.prop1 = $cookies.get('test1');
this.prop2 = 'nothing';
this.resultphone = {};

this.method1 = function(isValid, resultphone) {
    if(isValid){
        var funcJSON = resultphone;
        funcJSON.wleadid = '1';//resultphone is undefined in debugger here
        alert("just a filler to add breakpoint for debugger");
        $http.post('/some-test-service', funcJSON).then(
            function(response) {
                prop2 = response.data.content;
            }
        );
    }
};

}]);
```

Here is the code for `someroute.js`:

```
angular
.module('someroute', ['someclass'])
.controller('someroute', function($scope, someclass) {

    $scope.someclass = someclass;

});
```

Here is `someroute.html`:

```
someclass.prop1 is: {{someclass.prop1}} <br>
someclass.prop2 is: {{someclass.prop2}} <br>
<div ng-show="someclass.prop1!='yes'">
    <h1>someclass prop1!</h1>
    <div ng-include="'someroute_start.html'"></div>
</div>
<div ng-show="someclass.prop1=='yes'">

    <div ng-show="someclass.prop2=='showfirst'">
        <h1>Include start.</h1>
        <div ng-include="'someroute_first.html'"></div>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="someclass.prop2=='showsecond'">
        <h2>Include second.</h2>
        <div ng-include="'someroute_second.html'"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is `someroute_start.html`, which includes the form that needs to be handled by `someclass.js`:

```
    <form name="confirmForm" ng-submit="someclass.method1(confirmForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        Enter some value: 
        <input type="text" name="phonenum1" ng-model="resultphone.phonenum1" required />
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="confirmForm.$invalid" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

For completeness, I am including `someroute_first.html`, which is as simple as:

```
<h3>Showing first! </h3>
```

And `someroute_second.html`, which is as simple as:

```
<h3>Showing second! </h3>
```

The main controller for the app is `hello.js`, which I am including here in case part of the solution includes initializing `someclass`:

```
angular
    .module('hello', [ 'ngRoute', 'someclass', 'home', 'someroute', 'navigation' ])
    .config(

            function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

                $routeProvider.when('/', {
                    templateUrl : 'home.html',
                    controller : 'home'
                })
                .when('/someroute', {
                    templateUrl : 'someroute.html',
                    controller : 'someroute'
                }).otherwise('/');

                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

            }
    )
```

For completelness, `index.html` loads the modules as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style type="text/css">
    [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak { display: none !important; }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="ng-cloak" ng-cloak="" ng-app="hello">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="navigation">
      <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('home')}">
          <a href="#/">home</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{active:tab('someroute')}">
          <a href="#/someroute">some route</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="someclass.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="home.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="someroute.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="navigation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="hello.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Again, all of the above code is included in [a bare minimum excerpt of code required to reproduce the problem at this plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JInT1u1n79M6HNW7qtNZ).  **So what specific changes need to be made to 1.) get the plnkr to work and 2.) get the form data to be passed into the call to `someclass.method1()`?**

Comment: `<input type="text" name="phonenum1" ng-model="resultphone.phonenum1" required />` should be `<input type="text" name="phonenum1" ng-model="someclass.resultphone.phonenum1" required />`

Comment: @shakib Thank you, but changing that line did not solve the problem.  `resultphone` and `funcJSON` are undefined in `someclass.method1()`, and the program simply stops running after the eclipse debugger gives the line `funcJSON.wleadid = '1';` in that method.  Perhaps if we could get the plnkr to work, it might be easier to debug.  The version running on my devbox in firefox works as described in this comment after your suggestion.  Any other ideas?

Comment: added the `ngCookies` module script reference and changed the cookies code in `someclass.js`. running plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/JInT1u1n79M6HNW7qtNZ

Comment: @shakib You also added `var $this = this;`, which was a critical part of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look your plunker updated. Excellent.

Only an issue on someclass.js... you need to use "$this" variable at internal functions to access the correct scope:

```
$http.post('/some-test-service', funcJSON).then(
    function(response) {
        $this.prop2 = response.data.content;
    }
);
```

Comment: Your code causes the value of `prop2` to update in the view so that it is equal to `showfirst`, but the view does not update in any other way, meaning that the form is still visible, and the include file does not change.  What do I change to enable this final piece of the working example?

Comment: I am going to mark this as accepted and +1 because you answered the question of how to get data from the view into the service.  However, I have posted a different question about how to get data back from a similar service to refresh a view.  Your answer to this question does not result in the view updating, and the code in this OP does not let the data truly update because this OP relies on a disconnected backend service.  Are you willing to comment on the other question?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167161/re-usable-service-not-refreshing-view-in-angularjs

Comment: I will comment at the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Is the form submit function correct?

I'm not sure if I fallow you guys, but if the problem is with passing form data to someclass.method1, I would try something like this:

```
ng-submit="someclass.method1(confirmForm.$valid,someclass.resultphone)"
```

instead of this:

```
ng-submit="someclass.method1(confirmForm.$valid)"
```

The someclass.method1 definition looks like

```
this.method1 = function(isValid, resultphone) {...}
```

right?

Comment: considering this here's modified plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/JInT1u1n79M6HNW7qtNZ?p=preview