# Why won't re-usable service refresh view in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

An html view in AngularJS contains a form that sends its data through the view's ccontroller and into a reusable service.  The re-usable service receives the form's value, and is charged with updating the values of two cookies whose values should be printed in the view.  In my devbox, the FireFox debugger shows that the form's data enters the serice's handler method.  But the view is not beiing updated with the values of the cookies which are changed by the service's form handler.  Specifically, view elements should be shown or hidden based on the values of cookies that are changed by the form's handler.  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below so that the cookie values changed by the form handler are able to change the content that is shown in the view?**

All of the code required to recreate this probblem is in [the plnkr that you can examine by clicking on this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zjF1klLKmW4RhaX6vQsp), and you can recreate the problem by following the gui to `/someroute` (from the drop down navigation menu) and entering a value in the form.

The re-usable service is `someclass.js`, and its content is here:

```
angular
.module('someclass', ['ngCookies'])
.service('someclass', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$cookies', function($rootScope, $http, $cookies){
    var $this = this;
    this.prop1 = $cookies['test1'];
    this.prop2 = $cookies['test2'];
    this.resultphone = {};

    this.method1 = function(isValid, resultphone) {
        if(isValid){
            var funcJSON = $this.resultphone;
            funcJSON.wleadid = '1';
            $cookies.test1 = 'yes';
            if(funcJSON.phonenum1=='ok'){
              $cookies.test2 = 'ok';
            } else {
              $cookies.test2 = 'notok';
            }
        }
    };

    }]);
```

The html view is `someroute.html`, and its content is:

```
someclass.prop1 is: {{someclass.prop1}} <br>
someclass.prop2 is: {{someclass.prop2}} <br>
<div ng-show="someclass.prop1!='yes'">
    <h1>someclass prop1!</h1>
    <div ng-include="'someroute_start.html'"></div>
</div>
<div ng-show="someclass.prop1=='yes'">
    Inside prop1 is yes.  <br>
    <div ng-show="someclass.prop2=='ok'">
        <h1>Include start.  ok. </h1>
        <div ng-include="'someroute_first.html'"></div>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="someclass.prop2!='ok'">
        <h2>Include second.  NOT ok. </h2>
        <div ng-include="'someroute_second.html'"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The web form in `someroute_start.html` referred to above is:

```
    <form name="confirmForm" ng-submit="someclass.method1(confirmForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        Enter some value: 
        <input type="text" name="phonenum1" ng-model="someclass.resultphone.phonenum1" required />
        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="confirmForm.$invalid" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

The controller for `someroute.html` is `someroute.js`, and its code is:

```
angular
.module('someroute', ['someclass'])
.controller('someroute', function($scope, someclass) {

    $scope.someclass = someclass;

});
```

All of the remaining code required to reproduce the problem is in [the plnkr that you can examine by clicking on this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zjF1klLKmW4RhaX6vQsp).  **What specific changes need to be made to the code in the plnkr to get the `someroute.html` view to be refreshed/changed based on the `someclass.js` service's handling of the view's form data?**

Note that you can clear the cookies and restart the test by clicking the logout button in the GUI.

Comment: just start a timer to check the cookie value say every second.

Comment: @sdfacre Where would I put the timer in the `plnkr` code, and what would it look like.  I am googling `$interval`, but I have not used that tool before.

Comment: see http://plnkr.co/edit/QcV0l62lBhGebhtNjf84?p=preview

Comment: @sdfacre You may have fixed it if your code becomes `$interval(function(){if($cookies['test1'] !==$this.prop1){$this.prop1 = $cookies['test1'];} if($cookies['test2'] !==$this.prop2){$this.prop2 = $cookies['test2'];}}, 1000);`, but I cannot test it until the logout() link works, which I activate by changing the following in `index.html`:  `<a ng-href='logout()' ng-click='logout()' >logout</a>`. But enabling `logout()` causes your code to break because it empties cookies and `/someroute` does not work with empty cookies. Are you willing to look at `logout()` so that your code can be testable?

Comment: there are couple of problems in your code, I have fixed them now. please check the plunker again.

Comment: @sdfacre  Thank you.  If you feel like writing that up as an answer, I would be happy to mark it accepted and +1.  Also, any explanation of what you did would be greatly valued.  I will decompose it and study it tomorrow.

Comment: Your method1 has a useless "resultphone" parameter. You can remove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$interval` to check the cookie value should work for you.

However, there are other problems in your code as well:

```
1. nagivation controller is not used, hence, logout doesn't work
2. $cookie API of version 1.3+ is used while you are using angular 1.2
```

[This plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QcV0l62lBhGebhtNjf84?p=preview) has them all fixed.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for helping me with this.

Comment: Ok, it answered the question, but the $timeout has adding a complexity where a single $this.prop = value could resolve the watching problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to isolate the concerns... use $cookie to update cookie values, and $this to update scoped values. Is's not an $watch problem, only occur because "prop1" and "prop2" ignore the cookies contents:

```
this.method1 = function(isValid) {
    if(isValid){
        var funcJSON = $this.resultphone;
        funcJSON.wleadid = '1';
        $cookies.test1 = 'yes';
        if(funcJSON.phonenum1=='ok'){
          $cookies.test2 = 'ok';
          $this.prop2 = 'ok';
        } else {
          $cookies.test2 = 'notok';
          $this.prop2 = 'notok';
        }
    }
};
```

I made a updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bKpuXClYlUn4gAVYVcdv?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to help me.

Comment: I have read... thank you for explain... I liked the $timeout solution too :-)